# Background Service using thread

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-developer-api

1. How can i send location to server even when application closes
2. Is there any code please share with me.
3. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We can not directly provide you code because of your knowledge, We suggest you step or some code snap which guides you.

. Implement firebase Job Dispatcher [Firebase JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android)
. After successful adding library creates one service which extending JobService like bellow.

```
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobParameters;
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobService;

public class MyJobService extends JobService {
    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters job) {
        // Do some work here
        //getLatestLocationAndUpdateOnserver()
        //Don't miss to reschedule job
        return false; // Answers the question:z "Is there still work going on?"
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
        return false; // Answers the question: "Should this job be retried?"
    }
}
```

. Finally, Schedule Job-like bellow

```
private void scheduleJob() {
        FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(this));
        Bundle myExtrasBundle = new Bundle();
        myExtrasBundle.putString("request_sender", "Data Want to add");
        com.firebase.jobdispatcher.Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setService(MyJobService.class) // the JobService that will be called
                .setTag("my-unique-tag")
                .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(600, 610)) //this will fire after 10minute 
                .setReplaceCurrent(true)// uniquely identifies the job
                .setExtras(myExtrasBundle)
                .build();
        if (dispatcher != null) {
            dispatcher.cancel("my-unique-tag");
        }
        dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.If there is any other possible code please suggest me.

Comment: I suggest JobSchedular because after Orea android not directly support to run service using startService().